# Нужна запятая перед оборотом «как, так и»?

Tags: пунктуация

Осведомлённость в этой сфере позволит разработчикам учитывать стилевые аспекты осознанно, а не интуитивно(,) как на этапе проектирования, так и на этапе целевого использования.

Comment: @Нижегородец Пожалуйста, оформляйте ответы не комментариями, а ответами, чтобы другие участники могли дать оценку Вашей грамотности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Осведомлённость в этой сфере позволит разработчикам учитывать стилевые аспекты осознанно, а не интуитивно **как на этапе проектирования, так и на этапе целевого использования**.*

Обстоятельственные обороты (как? когда?) неоднородны, запятая не нужна.

Если автор хочет придать **уточняющее** значение второму обороту, то можно добавить присоединительный союз:

*Осведомлённость в этой сфере позволит разработчикам учитывать стилевые аспекты осознанно, а не интуитивно*, ***причем как на этапе проектирования, так и на этапе целевого использования***

Comment: Спасибо большое!